# How to parse JSON url with NextJS + TypeScript and display information?

Tags: jquery, json, reactjs, typescript, next.js

So I have been researching everywhere for this but wasn't able to reach a sensible conclusion. I imported { useRouter } from next/router and successfully parsed a local JSON file, but I would like to parse a JSON object from a URL. Here is one URL for example: http://time.jsontest.com/

I feel like I have tried everything but failed... Basically I am using Shopify API and want to access our database of customers from a JSON for a Dashboard. We are experimenting with NextJS and TypeScript right now, but I don't know. I find it tedious. I just need one example or resource that can help me..

Comment: I may misunderstand your question but are you trying to fetch the data? Something like this: `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json))`, but in TypeScript?

Comment: @Hangindev Yes I have been trying to do just that. I am quite new to this, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the data obtained from a JSON object from a URL with the Next.JS [api-routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) with TypeScript in your API response, you can do this:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

interface Time {
  date: string;
  milliseconds_since_epoch: number;
  time: string;
}

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method !== 'GET') {
    res.status(500).json({message: 'Desculpe, só aceitamos solicitações GET '});
  } else {
    const response = await fetch('http://time.jsontest.com/');
    const data: Time = await response.json();
    res.status(200).json({
      'date': data.date,
      'time in ms': data.milliseconds_since_epoch,
      'time': data.time
    })
  }
}
```

Place this code inside

```
root/
├── _src
│   └── _pages
│       └── _api
│           └── myApiTest.ts
```

To test the file, access http://localhost:3000/api/myApiTest

Ps. I'm using **nextjs v10.0.8**